# mp4 render output is too compressed - video editor

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor, compression

container: MPEG-4
video codec: MPEG-4
lossless
realtime encoding

render preview shows high quality rendered frames, but mp4 file is evidently far worse, despite hd settings.

Comment: Hello and welcome, the most recommended method to render is using Image sequences, that way you keep the best quality possible and then you just need to use a video editor (like the one included in Blender) or compositor to output a video format

Comment: @izer Have you tried other lossless codecs, so you can say it is an issue of this specific codec? If it is "too compressed" with others too - you have probably some issue with your setup or original files.